# Gulp cannot inject css and js at the same time

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

I am trying to run the following code

`var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({ lazy: true });    // fetches gulp plugins`

```
gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
     var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

    return gulp
    .src(config.index)
    .pipe(wiredep(config.wiredepDefaultOptions))      //wiredep injection configuration
    .pipe($.inject(gulp.src(config.js)))              //custom js files configuation
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.client))
});



/* inject bower and other injections */
   gulp.task('inject', ['styles-compile', 'wiredep'], function () {
     return gulp
       .src(config.index)
       .pipe($.inject(gulp.src(config.css)))
       .pipe(gulp.dest(config.client))
});
```

// if I comment the following line 
     `.pipe($.inject(gulp.src(config.css)))`

Then my .js files get inject otherwise they do not, from what I understand this injection happens in parallel.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why can't you use a simple `gulp.src`. And can you explain what does `$.inject` do?

Comment: $.inject is the same as gulp-inject, I have "gulp-load-plugins" installed which loads all the modules in var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({ lazy: true });    // fetches gulp plugins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gulp-inject` will only inject one set of files, replacing the old set with the new set each time you call it. There are two ways to solve the problem.

1) From the `gulp-inject` github page: use the `event-stream` plugin to combine the two streams of filenames (.css and .js) into a single stream which you pass to inject.

```
var es = require('event-stream'),
    inject = require('gulp-inject');

// Concatenate vendor scripts
var vendorStream = gulp.src(['./src/vendors/*.js'])
  .pipe(concat('vendors.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));

// Concatenate AND minify app sources
var appStream = gulp.src(['./src/app/*.js'])
  .pipe(concat('app.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));

gulp.src('./src/index.html')
  .pipe(inject(es.merge(vendorStream, appStream)))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
```

2) An alternative solution which may suit your current code organisation better is to use the `gulp-inject` `name` parameter to define two different places to inject. Thus you have a header file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My index</title>
  <!-- styles:css -->
  <!-- the styles files will be injected here -->
  <!-- endinject -->
</head>
<body>

  <!-- scripts:js -->
  <!-- the scripts files will be injected here -->
  <!-- endinject -->
</body>
</html>
```

and then your `gulpfile.js` contains something like:

```
var inject = require('gulp-inject');

gulp.src('./src/index.html')
  .pipe(inject(gulp.src('./config.css'), {name: 'styles'}))
  .pipe(inject(gulp.src('./config.js'), {name: 'scripts'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
```